# A Vlookup function (in Excel) exceeding 255 characters with wildcard

Tags: excel, vlookup

What is an alternative to a vlookup function that can look for cells with more than 255 characters, AND do wildcard searches?

I tried the following format and wildcard searches do not work: =INDEX(H$2:H$10,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(G$2:G$10="*"&A2&"*",0),0))

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own vlookup based on wildcard, this would be a good start:

```
Function WildcardVlookup(lookupValue As Range, lookupRange As Range, offset As Long) As Variant

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim a, b As String

    a = "*" & lookupValue.value & "*"

    For Each cell In lookupRange.Columns(1).Cells
        b = cell.value
        If b Like a Then
            WildcardVlookup = cell.offset(0, offset - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```